# Django models filter by foreignkey

Tags: django, filter, foreign-keys, models

I'm having some trouble in filtering objects from a set of models. Here is the problem:

I have 3 classes:

```
class Autor(models.Model):    
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, blank=True, unique=True)
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to='autores/', null=True, blank=True)
    ...

class CategoriaRecolha(models.Model):
    categoria = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    descricao = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=30, blank=True, unique=True)
    ...

class Recolha(models.Model):    
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True, unique=True)
    descricao = models.TextField()
    ficha_tec = models.TextField()
    categoria = models.ForeignKey(CategoriaRecolha)
    autor = models.ForeignKey(Autor)
    ....
```

What I'm trying to retrieve is the fields of the class Autor, in which the field categoria of the class Recolha is equal to a specific value.

In a more simple way, I need to get the all the autor that have participated in a specific categoria.

Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A more direct alternative:

```
autors = Autor.objects.filter(recolha__categoria=MyCategoria)
```

where `MyCategoria` is the relevant `CategoriaRecolha` instance. Or, if you want to match agains the specific category name, you can extend the query another level:

```
autors = Autor.objects.filter(recolha__categoria__categoria='my_category_name')
```

Answer (score 23):

in django 2  is ForeignKey.limit_choices_to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/)

```
staff_member = models.ForeignKey(
    User,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    limit_choices_to={'is_staff': True},
)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
cat = CategoriaRecolha.objects.get(field=value)
rows = Recolha.filter(categoria=cat)
autors = [row.autor for row in rows]
```

The [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) explain this pretty well.