# Django filter foreignkey field

Tags: python, django, filter, foreign-keys

**Short version:**

I have a Django app used for recipes, and want to filter data to be sent to a template in my view. I basically want all recepies that are added by a specific user to be sent as context. The following filtering returns an error message **invalid literal for int() with base 10: *my_username***.

```
recipes = Recipe.objects.filter(added_by = uname)
```

The variable *uname* is passed from a template. On the other hand, filtering on *request.user* works fine, but is not what I want.

```
recipes = Recipe.objects.filter(added_by = request.user)
```

**Details:**

My models are given (relevant fields) as:

```
class Recipe (models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Where *User* is an existing Django user. When I call {{ recipe.added_by }} in my template, I get the username as wanted. This username is passed on to a view with *href="/profile/{{recipe.added_by}}"*, where the view looks like the following:

```
def profile(request, uname):

    print uname #Correct username printed
    print request.user #Logged in user (not relevant, as userprofile should be visible for all)

    recipes = Recipe.objects.filter(added_by = uname) #Does not work. Why?
    #recipes = Recipe.objects.filter(added_by = request.user)

    form = CommentForm(request.POST)

    context = {
        'uname': uname,
        'recipes': recipes,
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, '*app_name*/profile.html', context)
```

Not sure what I am missing, but from what I can tell, it seems to have something to do with the fact that *added_by* has a Foreign Key to a User. I also tried to change the filter argument to *recipe__added_by__added_by = uname* according to [1], but Django then returned an error saying "Cannot resolve keyword 'recipe' into field", which seems obvious. My url is:

```
url(r'^profile/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$', 'profile', name='*app_name*-profile'),
```

Thanks for any reply. Sorry if this should have been obvious.

[1] [Django models filter by foreignkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508744/django-models-filter-by-foreignkey)

Comment: Is your recipe.added_by user same as the logged in user?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try like:

```
 recipes = Recipe.objects.filter(added_by__username = uname)
```

And `request.user` works fine for `Recipe.objects.filter(added_by = request.user)` because `request.user` is an object. details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Comment: I think uname denotes any username not only the logged in user's username.

Comment: Happy to help @kennha . If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted (which is a check mark in left of the answer)

Answer (score 1):

When child class defined as

```
class Recipe (models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

makemigration generates foreign key as **added_by_id**. 
So, you have to use corresponding field name in filter.

Eg: `recipes = Recipe.objects.filter(added_by_id = uname)`