# Django how to get something by foreign key' value?

Tags: django, sqlite

I have a model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Strategy(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mod_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    strategy_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    strategy = models.TextField()
    position = models.TextField()
```

I want to get username = "leo".

But in  Strategy's user is using user_id.

How to get "models.Strategy.objects.get" or "models.Strategy.objects.filter" using username = "leo"?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django models filter by foreignkey](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508744/django-models-filter-by-foreignkey)

Answer (score 3):

Duplicated question [Django models filter by foreignkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508744/django-models-filter-by-foreignkey)

```
Strategy.objects.filter(user__username='leo').first()
```

or

```
try:
    Strategy.objects.get(user__username='leo')
except Strategy.DoesNotExists():
    print 'username Leo does not exists'
```

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)